# Speed of linear dynamical system trajectory

Tags: linear-algebra, lds

[warning: biologist asking a math question]

In a linear dynamical system (LDS), what feature of the matrix controls the speed of the trajectory in state space?

Say I have a matrix **M** describing how the LDS evolves per discrete time unit *t*. State after 10 *t* is given by **M**^10, and I'll call it the final state.
For the same initial condition, how should I modify **M** to make it reach the final state in arbitrary fewer (or more) time steps? Is it trivial?

thanks,

Comment: "biologist asking a math question" makes this most likely off-topic for SO, please check out the other sites in the Stack Exchange Network, I'm sure you'll find something that fits better. Actually, it's the "math" part, much less the "biologist" part ;)

Comment: @reto Does it get any better if I add "... in Octave" at the end? :)
Just kidding - I asked it at math.stackexchange.Thanks for pointing out.